# UICollectionView with 1 column in Portrait mode and 2 in Landscape mode?

Tags: ios, swift

Can I have a `UICollectionView` with:

- 1 column in `portrait` mode and
- 2 columns in `landscape` mode

working on all of the following devices? 
`iPhone`, `iPhone Max`, `iPad`

It should always scrolling `vertically`, just the number of columns switch between 1 and 2, when I rotate the device.

Can I get this by just constraining the width of the cells? But how to make it flexible depending on the device?

Comment: You can set minimum or maximum width logic inside the flow layout. It's more convenient than device orientation

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini You mean that I don't need to check for the device orientation, correct? I can just tune min and max so that it display 2 columns in portrait mode on all devices? Could you elaborate a bit more? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Device orientation is not always a good idea for this. Because portrait mode of a device could be wider than landscape mode of another! Think about 12 inch iPad and iPhone SE.

So better approach is to set minimum or maximum with for each cell in a custom `FlowLayout`

As an example. take a look at this:

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return assertionFailure("Collection view not found") }

        let availableWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
        let minimumColumnWidth: CGFloat = 150
        let maxNumberOfItems = Int(availableWidth/minimumColumnWidth)
        let numberOfItems = min(maxNumberOfItems, collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))
        let itemWidth = availableWidth / CGFloat(numberOfItems).rounded(.down)
        itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: 102)
    }
}
```

This code fills the screen with items with minimum 150pt for width. So if `collectionView` width is between (150...299), you will have just one column. if it is between (300...449), you will get two! and so on!

So think before using the logic:

- Should I have just two columns for a landscape 12" iPad? or It may be
  better to fill the screen with more objects?
- Should I change the code a bit to have maximum number of items to keep elements in the reading area space?
- Should I just check for orientation (`height < width ? .landscape : .portrait`) in this code to match the answer to my original question without need to posting a new one?
- Should I use `sectionInset` and `scrollDirection` here as I need?

Comment: That's sound like a good solution, thanks. I will implement and let you know.

Comment: Hey, did you try it? @aneuryzm

Comment: Hi, yes I used a similar logic using sizeForItem method from UICollectionView delegate, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar with one of my projects. The code below also makes changes based on whether or not the width is less than the height (i.e. portrait vs landscape). It get's called when the orientation changes.

```
let margins: CGFloat = 16

func updateFlowLayout() {
    guard let flowLayout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
        return
    }

    let cellsPerRow: CGFloat = (self.view.bounds.width < self.view.bounds.height ? 1 : 2)
    let insets = self.view.safeAreaInsets.left + self.view.safeAreaInsets.right
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (self.collectionView.bounds.width - insets - margins * (cellsPerRow + 1)) * (1.0 / cellsPerRow), height: 120)
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: margins, bottom: margins, right: margins)
}
```